# How to implement optimistic state update / push using React, Redux and Redux-Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to implement optimistic state update so I update state immediately on update action and then perform undo & notify user if update request fails.

I have following worker and watcher sagas:

```
// Worker Saga
function* updateItem(action) {

    // Update state optimistically
    yield put({type: UPDATE_ITEM_OPTIMISTICALLY, payload: action.payload});

    try {
            const response = yield call(axios.post, `${API_URL}/updateItem`, action.payload);
        } catch (e) {
            // Undo state push
            yield put({type: UNDO_UPDATE_ITEM, payload: action.meta.currentState});
        }
}

// Watcher Saga
function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(UPDATE_ITEM, updateItem);
}
```

I am passing currentState in action so I can push back to it in case of request failure.

The problem with this approach is that UPDATE_ITEM_OPTIMISTICALLY action resolves before saga code and meta.currentState is then updated before its used within catch block.

Comment: I don't quite get the issue: you put your currentState in the action (UPDATE_ITEM), perform a UPDATE_ITEM_OPTIMISTICALLY, then do a API call. When the call fails, you do a UNDO_UPDATE_ITEM with the currentstate from the action.
How can that currentState be different? It's included in you action (meta field) as it was when you dispatched the UPDATE_ITEM call.

Comment: I thought to hold present state in action.meta.currentState - state before the update. Its not different because reducers are hit first before sagas run. I had an idea to send currentState in action creator to be able to undo to that state if call fails. For example I am editing item attributes and would like to show edit effects immediately and not wait for API to confirm those changes are saved. If API returns error I would like to undo state back to action.meta.currentState. Which approach do you suggest for optimistic state updates and eventual state undo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Pass a deep copy of currentState to action payload (kind of slow)
2. Keep a second field in your reducer called prevState and assign the props you need from current state to it, then use it in your saga